# Enable scaffold in vaadin on grails application

Tags: grails, vaadin, scaffold

i am creating a web-app with grails and vaadin, but i have a big problem with grails scaffold.

After installing vaadin-grails plugin i can't access to scaffold,
i try to change url mapping without results.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no scaffolding for Vaadin in Grails. The approach you should follow:

1. Put your domain classes to a new plugin.
2. Create a new Grails project, reference your domain plugin, create controllers for scaffolding.
3. Create a new Grails project with Vaadin and reference your domain plugin

That means, you will run two Grails applications, one for "administration" with scaffolding and the second one, for "business" people, running with Vaadin.